# mirror of active window by gstreamer

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, window, gstreamer

I can make a mirror of an active window by gstreamer:
([Mirroring the currently focussed window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384719/mirroring-the-currently-focussed-window))

```
gst-launch-1.0 ximagesrc xid=<window_id> ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

then I moved it on a second screen (displayed by projector), and it's ok.

However, when I cover the primary window in the first screen by another application window, then the content of the mirrored one disappears. Is there any way to keep it visible, independently what I am doing on the first screen?